# edit the first option name

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which I do not have access to.

What I want to do is add some text into the first option which is now empty. Text such as "Select Address"

```
<select name="My_Saved_Billing"
onChange="Choose_My_Saved_Billing(this.selectedIndex)" style="background-color:#EEEEEE">
<option></option>
<option value="1394">text</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$('select[name=My_Saved_Billing] > option:first-child')
    .text('Select Address');
```

If you want to find the empty option(s), not just the first one, use:

```
$('select[name=My_Saved_Billing] > option:empty')
// or
$('select[name=My_Saved_Billing] > option:empty:first')
```

To get the option with specific content, use:

```
$('select[name=My_Saved_Billing] > option:contains(texthere)')
```

Comment: This worked great, just a side question is, how would automatically select the first option that had a value or option text whichever is easier to code.

Comment: @user357034, I would recommend storing the initial selector in a variable.  That way, you get the same item regardless if the text changes.

Comment: I do not understand you previous comment. Or perhaps I didn't fully explain myself. Right now there are two options the first which is originally empty and the second which has a value and text. If there is no options with either a value or text how would we change the first option to say something else instead of "select address" like "Enter Address" I assume we have to check to see if all options values are null or text=""

Comment: "If there is no options with either a value or text"  You can test for this using `$('select[name=My_Saved_Billing] > option:not(:empty)').length === 0`.  Or by checking value: `$('select[name=My_Saved_Billing] > option[value=]').length === 0`

Answer (score 11):

```
$("select[name=My_Saved_Billing] option:first").text("Select Address");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VGhdX/

To answer your side question from your comment (if I understand correctly):

> how would automatically select the
>   first option that had a value or
>   option text whichever is easier to
>   code

You can do this using the [Has Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/):

```
$("select[name=My_Saved_Billing] option[value]:first").text("Foo");
```

The Has Attribute selector will ignore present attributes which contain empty values (so `value=""` will *not* match).

Comment: This one worked as well. Two correct answers, how do I choose? LOL

Comment: Problem is I do not know what could be in the text. Is there something like .text(!="")

Comment: @user357034 Try `option[text!= '']:first`