# How to set first option's of Select Box using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select list:

```
<select id='sf-field-1'> 
    <option></option> 
    <option value="1">one</option> 
    <option value="2">two</option> 
    <option value="3">three</option> 
</select>
```

How can I set the value of option value to the below by using jQuery?

```
<select id='sf-field-1'> 
    <option> -- Select -- </option> 
    <option value="1">one</option> 
    <option value="2">two</option> 
    <option value="3">three</option> 
</select>
```

I also tried `jQuery("#sf-field-1 :first-child").attr("value", 0);` but this did not work for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second attempt was close, you just need to set the `text()` of the element, not its value:

```
$("#sf-field-1 :first-child").text(" -- Select -- ");
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b8oLg49x/)

Comment: If you want to set the value to 0 add this : $("#sf-field-1 :first-child").val(0);

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is using prepend function :
What you do is that create dropdownlist with select options

```
<select id='sf-field-1'> 
    <option value="1">one</option> 
    <option value="2">two</option> 
    <option value="3">three</option> 
</select>
```

and then using following jquery code add first option.

```
    var newOption = "<option selected='"+"selected"+"  '>--Select--</option>"; 
$("#sf-field-1").prepend(newOption);
```

Answer (score 0):

based on [edit the first option name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473916/edit-the-first-option-name) You can use

```
$('#sf-field-1 > option:empty:first').text(" -- Select -- ");
```